# Why does Firefox have a different scrollbar appearance?

Tags: html, css, styles, overflow

I faced the following problem - in the Firefox browser the scrollbar appearance is different, it is placed inside the div and changes the `ul` width.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zmatj6s9/

I am trying to figure out what should I change to have the same layout in both browsers. Any thoughts?

```css
.a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px;;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: brown
}

.sidebar {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
    flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <ul class='ul'>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class='a'>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps is not he solution you want, but is an aproach. If you just extend the `ul` several pixels and hide the overflow content you will be able to scroll and won't see any scrollbar at all.

As I said, perhaps is not the solution, but I've applied sometimes in my projects and it works fine. You can always use some scrollbar plugin, but if you want it in plane css, I think this is the closer solution. Hope it helps to you.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row warp;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: brown;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul {
  width: calc(100% + 25px);
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 6</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 7</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 8</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">ELEMENT 9</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I have clean up your code because you have some unnecessary DOM elements, at least for this example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I have a requirement to keep the scrollbar visible, but it is a nice approach, might be useful in the future.

Comment: If its the case you can only use a plugin to solve that, because I pretty sure that firefox doesn't allow scrollbar customization. This plugin could help you to solve your problem: https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar

Comment: @ToniBordoy Firefox now does allow minimal control over the scrollbar.  You can use `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width`.  The first takes two colours to control the bar and gutter colours, but width only accepts a couple of preset options - no pixel widths sadly

Comment: @DMcCallum83 thanks for the info. Will take a look when I have to solve problems like this.